# How can I spawn multiple tkMessageBox.showerror at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am creating a little time management tool, using Tkinter, so I can keep on task at work.  I am having trouble with one aspect that I cannot seem to get working.  I'm using the error box so that it is displayed in front of all other windows.

As it is now, the program starts a new thread on a function that keeps track of time, and compares it to the time the user entered for their task.  Once real time > the time entered by the user, it starts another thread to spawn the tkMessageBox.  I have tried this without starting a new thread to spawn the tkMessageBox, and the problem is the same.  If the user enters the same time for 2 separate tasks, the error pop up freezes.  I'm having trouble finding information on this topic specifically...  The behaviour is odd because if I have 2 alerts, lets say 1 at 0600 and one at 0601, but I do not close the first error box that pops up and let it stay up until the second alert triggers, the second alert will just replace the first one(I would like multiple error boxes to pop up if possible).  It's only the alerts that have the same trigger time that cause the pop up to freeze though.

This is my first GUI program and only started learning the concept of threading, and GUIs in the past 24 hours, so I'm not sure if this is a problem with threading or the tkMessageBox.  Because of the behaviour of the error box, I’m thinking it is the thread module combined with the tkMessageBox module.  The command I'm using is:

```
tkMessageBox.showerror('TIMER ALERT!!!', comp_msg)
```

[Here is the source](http://pastebin.com/Tap6QKgy)  I put comments in there to help.  The tkMessageBox I’m talking about is line 56.

I guess I'm not sure if I can even do what I am trying to do with the pop-up box, if I can, I'm not sure how.  If I can't, is there a alternative way to spawn multiple error type pop-up boxes with Tkinter?  I just want multiple boxes to be able to appear at any given time.

Thanks in advance, and I really appreciate any help at all.

EDIT:

```
import thread
from Tkinter import *

#Spawns Error Box.  Runs in it's own thread.
def message_box(comp_msg,q):      # q is an empty string because of thread module.
    print "Spawning Error Box..."
    eb =Toplevel()
    eb.config(master=None,bg="red")
    pop_l = Label(eb,text="ALERT!!!")
    pop_l2=Label(eb,text=comp_msg)
    pop_l.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
    pop_l2.pack(pady=15,padx=10)
    return eb

thread.start_new_thread(message_box,(comp_msg,""))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tkmessageBox default dialog boxes are [modal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window). You could implement a simple none modal dialog box for this application. [Here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) is a good document about creating custom dialog boxes.

This way you can create as many new custom dialog boxes as your app requires, since each one is just a new Toplevel.

Here is a simple Tkinter app that shows the clock on the main window. When you click on the button it starts new tkMessageBox dialog boxes in new threads. (If you run it) You could see that the main thread that runs the TK event loop is working (since the time is getting updated), but the error boxes are not showing up as expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime
import threading                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

class MyApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        if not root:
            root = Tk()
        self.time_var = StringVar()
        self.time_var.set('starting timer ...')

        self.root = root
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.init_widgets()
        self.update_time()

    def init_widgets(self):
        self.label = Label(self.root, textvariable=self.time_var)
        self.label.pack()
        self.btn = Button(self.root, text='show error', command=self.spawn_errors)
        self.btn.pack()

    def update_time(self):
        self.time_var.set( str(datetime.datetime.now()) )
        self.root.after(1000, self.update_time)

    def spawn_errors(self):
        for i in range(3):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.show_error)
            t.start()

    def show_error(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        tkMessageBox.showerror('Error: %s' % (str(now)), now)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you farzad!  I am more of a hobbyist when it comes to programming, so when classes are involved with Tkinter it goes way over my head.  I am looking at it anyway, to see if I can figure it out. I just have a hard time with classes as I have never had to use them before.  Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome. I added a sample code so you could use it as a base for your app.

Comment: Don't get intimidated about Classes. You've done the hardest thing which is taking the first step by actually starting coding. You could easily learn about all of this and Python is a clear an enjoyable language to learn/do programming. And whenever you had questions, you already know where to ask. ;)

Comment: Thanks again :D  Right now I have a version that is working using Toplevel(), instead of tkMessageBox().  Your initial post led me to find Toplevel() and it's exactly what i needed.  I am not using classes yet, but I am saving your example to study so I can learn how to implement classes.  I will have to go and watch some videos for the in depth explanations, but this is really great & the answer i needed. Thank you!